# How to view historical usage metrics, per process?

Tags: linux, monitoring, memory-usage, sar, statsd

My first inclination here would be something built into SAR, or the sysstat package in general. If that is indeed the case however, I can't seem to find this solution.

What I would like to see, and absolutely preferably through sysstat if possible, is a historical log of process usage (memory, CPU, etc.) in much the same format as SAR logs (if not already directly available through SAR files somehow). I know monitoring software is available, but I'm more-so looking for a mostly non-intrusive package, and actually something that could be parsed relatively intuitively via statsd/collectd.

Comment: See also [get memory usage per process with sar, sysstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531543/get-memory-usage-per-process-with-sar-sysstat) on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Run the sar command as a background process. The syntax for this is:

`sar -o datafile interval count >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

All data are captured in binary form and saved to a file (datafile).  The data can then be selectively displayed with the sar command using the -f option. Set the interval and count  parameters  to select  count records at interval second intervals. If the count parameter is not set, all the records saved in the file will be selected.  Collection of data in this manner is useful to characterize system usage over a period of time and determine peak usage hours.

Comment: Do you have an example execution that shows the output from `sar` that shows the **resource usage per process**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dumb while loop that prints the top processes' resource usage every 5 minutes.

```
while true; do
  date;
  ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-pcpu | head;
  echo;
  sleep 300;
done
```

The above will output the top 9 processes that are using the most CPU usage. To get the top 9 processes that are using the most memory, use:

```
while true; do
  date;
  ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-pmem | head;
  echo;
  sleep 300;
done
```

### Example

The following example output shows that apache is clearly our biggest CPU-consuming process.

```
Sun Jan 28 23:46:28 UTC 2024
  PID  PPID CMD                         %MEM %CPU
25130 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.7
12878 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.2  2.5
23903 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.4
  898 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
  902 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
  910 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
 8397 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
 9263 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
23911 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2

Sun Jan 28 23:51:28 UTC 2024
  PID  PPID CMD                         %MEM %CPU
25130 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.6
12878 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.2  2.4
23903 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.4
  898 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
  902 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
  910 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
 8397 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
 9263 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
23911 11432 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN  0.1  2.2
```

### Limitations

Obviously this sucks because it will only tell you the *instantaneous* resource usage at the exact moment in time when the command is run (every 5 minutes).

Ideally it would tell you the average resource usage over the *interval* of time between the outputs. But, seeing as this answer has been open for 7 years and there's no good answer -- it's better than nothing.

Leave it running overnight in a `screen` session, and by morning you'll have some better insight (with minimal effort).